# Rewrite rule ends up on undefined page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the `.htaccess` of my root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

To shortener urls I used this with success:

```
RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=explore&filter=$1   [NC]
```

In this case the url `https://example.com/index.php?a=explore&filter=latest%20music`
become `https://example.com/explore&filter=latest%20music`

My problem starts here...if I shorten this url:

```
https://example.com/index.php?a=search&q=something
```

using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$          index.php?a=search&q=$1    [NC]
```

The redirection doesn't work, I end up on an undefined page.

This is my JS function for the search:

```
function manageResults() {
    var q = $("#search").val();
    liveLoad('search&q='+q.replace(' ','+'));
}
```

Here is my full `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=explore&filter=$1   [NC]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$          index.php?a=search&q=$1    [NC]
RewriteRule ^welcome/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=welcome&filter=$1   [NC]
```

My `function.js` for the live search:

```
function liveSearch() {
    var q = $('#search').val();

    // If the query starts with #, do not execute anything
    if(q == '#') {
        $(".search-container").hide();
        $(".search-content").remove();
        return false;
    }

    // Check the notification state
    if(typeof notificationState != 'undefined') {
        showNotification('close');
    }

    // Search if the hashtag is typed
    if(q.indexOf('#') === -1) {
        var y = 'q';
        var url = 'people';
        $('#search').keypress(function(x){if(x.keyCode==13){q=$(this).val();if(q!=this.defaultValue){document.location='search&'+y+'='+q.replace(' ','+')}}});
    } else {
        var y = 'filter';
        var url = 'tags';
        $('#search').keypress(function(x){if(x.keyCode==13){q=$(this).val();if(q!=this.defaultValue){document.location='explore&'+y+'='+q.replace('#','')}}});
    }

    // If the text input is 0, remove everything instantly by setting the MS to 1
    if(q == 0) {
        var ms = 0;
    } else {
        $('.search-container').show();
        $('.search-container').html('<div class="search-content"><div class="search-results"><div class="message-inner"><div class="retrieving-results">Retrieving Results</div> <div class="preloader-left preloader-dark"></div></div></div></div>');
        var ms = 200;
    }

    // Start the delay (to prevent some useless queries)
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(q == $('#search').val()) {
            if(q == 0) {
                $(".search-container").hide();
                $(".search-content").remove();
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://example.com/requests/load_"+url+".php",
                data: 'q='+q+'&start=1&live=1', // start is not used in this particular case, only needs to be set
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".search-container").html(html).show();
                }
                });
            }
        }
    }, ms);

}
```

Comment: "The redirection doesn't work" - Try temporarily changing to an external redirect by adding the `R` flag. Does it redirect to the correct URL? Although `/search/<phrase>` looks as if it should be handled by your initial `RewriteRule` anyway? If you are using JS to grab the information from the URL in order to perform the search then it might require the JS to be updated (since the URL has now changed).

Comment: @w3d just added the `R` flag, but it doesn't work, even if I enter directly the URL. This works `/index.php?a=search&q=something`

Comment: Just to add, if you add the `R` flag you will also need to prefix the substitution with a slash ie. `/index.php?...` But are you saying there is no redirection at all? But as I also mentioned, this also looks like it would be handled by the first ruleset - so there is likely a conflict. Can you post your entire .htaccess file, since the order of directives is important.

Comment: @w3d I just edit my question.  For some reason if I try to access directly  the page I get the redirection to `/welcome` page

Comment: That redirect can't be caused by the directives posted above. (?)

Comment: @w3d I have a wrapper.html file that replace the path of the url from index to the path with raw content, one rule is `var custom = custom.replace('{$url}/', 'page.php?a=welcome');`

Comment: @w3d I added the live search function in my question. I know for sure the problem is in my JS that does not match what I have in my `.htaccess` file. But I have not enough knowledge to correct it.